# Any class in scala

Tags: scala, class

I am beginner in scala language, I am confused with `Any` class in scala.

```
def f(x: Any) = println(x)
```

is above code represents that `x` variable can be of any datatype(example:int,string etc.)

rewritten code:

```
def f(x:Any)=x+5
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(5)
 required: String
       def f(x:Any)=x+5
```

if `x` can accept any type then why am I getting above error. I might confused understanding of **any** in scala. Please correct me.

Comment: If `x` can be of any type, you cannot be sure that you will always be able to add 5. What happens if I call `f("hello");`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Your example would in theory be ok as you can append an `int` to a `String`. A better example would be some class that doesn't override the `+` operator.

Comment: Actually in case of an instance `a` of a class `A <: Any` and `b` of class `B`, an expression of the form `val c = a + x` is actually `a.+(x)` which means it will work only if your class A has  a method `def [B, C]+(b: B): C`.

Comment: @vivman please accept the answer if it solves your issue !

Answer (score 4):

In a statically typed language you can only call a method `m` on a value `x` of type `A` if `m` is defined by `A`. By the nature of `Any`, there aren't any useful methods on `Any` that you could call (except a few things like `toString` or `hashCode`), certainly no plus operation is defined. Imagine you passed a `Boolean` into that method, which is allowed since `Boolean` is a sub-type of `Any`. If the compiler allowed your code, it would run into a problem, because there is no such thing as `+` on a `Boolean`. In a dynamically typed language you could run that code and would then encounter a runtime error.

---

The error message looks weird, because you can concatenate strings with `+` and due to an implicit conversion it is possible to concatenate things with strings:

```
def f(x: Any) = x + "hello"  // implicitly converts x to a string

f(true)  // "truehello"
```

This is a source of great confusion and [hopefully](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-194) will disappear from the language. If you used a different method, the error would be more obvious:

```
def f(x:Any)=x-5

<console>:54: error: value - is not a member of Any
       def f(x:Any)=x-5
                     ^
```

Comment: Are you saying that implicits should be removed from the language?

Comment: @SamTebbs33 the method `any2stringadd` in `Predef` should be removed because it is very annoying. It is the reason for the strange wording of the error message here. Exchange `+` for `-` in the example, and you'll see the difference.

Comment: If there is a conversion from Any to String, why is the int 5 not getting converted to String? Int is a subclass of Any

Comment: @Samar There is no implicit conversion to String. There is an implicit conversion to an auxiliary type that defines concatenation with a String: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L280

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `println()` sources you will see:

```
    public void println(Object x) {
        String s = String.valueOf(x);
        synchronized (this) {
            print(s);
            newLine();
        }
    }
```

where `String.valueOf` is

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Class `Any` already has `toString` method but doesn't have `+` method (you know that all operators such `+`, `-` etc. are methods, see http://tomjefferys.blogspot.com/2011/11/operator-overloading-in-scala.html).

Comment: Thanks,understand the concept!!